# StackExchange.Redis mass insert across multiple threads hangs

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to insert millions of keys into Redis as quickly as possible. To do this, I'm trying to use multiple tasks.

```
var batchSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(5);
var batchTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var chunk in items.Chunk(50000))
{
    var batchTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await batchSlim.WaitAsync(token);
                
        var readonlyDb = _redisConn.GetDatabase();
        var tasks = chunk
            .Select(item => readonlyDb.HashSetAsync(
                $"item:{{{item.Id}}}", 
                item.ToHashEntries()
            ))
            .ToList();
                
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);                    
        batchSlim.Release(1);

    }, token);
    batchTasks.Add(batchTask);
}

await Task.WhenAll(batchTasks);
```

For context, the list of items contains 1 million items. I've tried different batch sizes, but I get this issue no matter what size.

This code might process the first 5 or even the second 5 just fine, but it always eventually hangs and just sits there.

I've tried adding Command.FireAndForget to the HashSetAsync call. That seems to fix the hanging issue, but then the process completes, and I only end up with around 300k of the 1 million items actually being inserted.

Is the StandExchange.Redis client thread safe? Is there a limit to how many commands you can send at once?

As for FireAndForget - what am I missing? I've seen multiple post recommending you use that for speed, but when I try it, I just get dropped missing keys.

UPDATE: After adding a try/catch, I'm getting this error on almost every task:

> Timeout awaiting response (outbound=314KiB, inbound=48354KiB, 19735ms
> elapsed, timeout is 10000ms), command=HMSET, next: HMSET ***, inst: 0,
> qu: 4943, qs: 0, aw: True, bw: Flushing, rs: DequeueResult, ws:
> Flushing, in: 0, last-in: 2, cur-in: 35, sync-ops: 0, async-ops:
> 2003999, serverEndpoint: ***:6379, conn-sec: 312.46, aoc: 0, mc:
> 1/1/0, mgr: 8 of 10 available, clientName:
> ***(SE.Redis-v2.6.122.38350), PerfCounterHelperkeyHashSlot: 2907, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=16,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=16,Max=32767), POOL:
> (Threads=49,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=941553,Timers=4), v:
> 2.6.122.38350 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:
> https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Yet, all the records wind up getting added. The qu value is different each time, but it's always very high. Would a large syncTimeout value fix this?